# Cannot create firebase project error at /v1/projects:migrateToFirebaseProject

Tags: firebase

Tried to create firebase project adding my existing Google Cloud project. It failed after last step:
[image]

It fails at this request which ends with `500` status code:

`POST https://mobilesdk-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/projects:migrateToFirebaseProject?key=XXXXX_REMOVED_XXXXX&alt=json`

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "2: \u003ceye3 title='/ThirdPartyFederatedService.SetOAuthAppConfig, INVALID_ARGUMENT'/\u003e APPLICATION_ERROR;apps.auth.proto/ThirdPartyFederatedService.SetOAuthAppConfig;client_id cannot be empty for provider: yahoo\ncom.google.net.rpc3.RpcException: OpenAuth::INPUT_ERROR: client_id cannot be empty for provider: yahoo

[REMOVED quite long stack trace here]",
    "status": "UNKNOWN",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.internal.firebase.v1.ErrorCode"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sort of question should go to Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Ok. I will try there. Thanks.